# The API 'sharepointonline' returned an invalid response for workflow operation 'When_an_item_is_created' of type 'OpenApiConnection'

Tags: openapi, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a scheduled flow that will get file properties and trigger.
After all the data entered the library I created the flow and turn on. After running the flow ill failure at the begins. Following error message parses.

> ResponseSwaggerSchemaValidationFailure. The API 'sharepointonline'
> returned an invalid response for workflow operation
> 'Get_files_(properties_only)' of type 'OpenApiConnection'. Error
> details: 'The API operation 'GetFileItems' is missing required
> property 'body/value/0/Supplier_x0020_Code'.'

I tried using a new flow and deleted that action. all the methods tried and not found any solution.

Comment: Can you show us the flow or at least give us some additional technical information that can help us identify what the issue is?

Comment: Can you provide us with an update on the status of your issue? If you are still facing this issue then please provide more context for us to test, thanks.